# Compute the value of $\lim_{x \to-\infty}Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

(After some recommendations , I feel I need to elaborate a little bit more on my question)
So I was solving Schrodiger's equation for a step:

$$ 
V(x)=
\begin{cases}  0 & x<0 \\
V_0 & x>0\\
  \end{cases},
$$

and in the region x $\in (-\infty,0)$ $V(x)=0$ so by solving Schrodinger's time-independent equation $\frac{d^2\psi}{d^2}-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}V(x)\psi=-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}E\psi \rightarrow \frac{d^2\psi}{d^2x}+\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}E\psi=0$ ended up with the general solution: $\psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}$

I was wondering why the writer does not apply the constraint that outside of the well $\psi(x)$ should be finite $\rightarrow \lim_{x\mapsto-\infty}\psi(x)=l \in R$. It is more like a calculus question but by applying this constraint do we get any information about A or B? Because if there weren't "$ik$'s " but plain $k$'s in the exponents we could gain that $A=0$

***Edit** After some discussion with my uni proffessor I found out why the writer does not demand $\psi$ to be finite when $x \to -\infty$ . The asnwer is : the solution $Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx} \equiv Asin(kx) + Bcos(kx)$ and we know that these trigonometric functions are finite anyway , so there is no need to investigate this.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly, but an oscillating function does not have a well-defined limit.

Comment: @flippiefanus isn't it that $\psi(x)$ must be finite everywhere ( and as a result in $x \to -\infty$ as well) ?

Comment: To reopen this post (v2), fix the mathjax for starters. Also why is the potential defined twice for $x<0$? Moreover, what is the sign of $V_0$?

Comment: Since $e^{ikx} = \cos kx + i\sin kx$, the limit you want isn't defined. The value keeps rotating around the complex unit circle forever.

Comment: After your edits things are a little clearer.  But your potential is not a finite well, it's *a finite step*.  That wording probably caused some confusion.  I'll take a stab at rewording your question.  This is my interpretation, and it may not be what you are after.  If so, tell us.   "I thought wave functions had to be normalizable, that is, you have to be able to integrate them to get a finite result.   This wave function does not have a finite integral.  Shouldn't the wave function decay as distance goes to infinity so that the thing can have a finite integral?"

Comment: @garyp oh I see.. I am sorry I never meant to confuse anybody , it's my first course in quantum mechanics and I am not a native englush speaker.. If you can reword it you are welcome.. Back to the physics: So you are actually implying that in oder a wave function to be finite , it needs to decay but my question is : if B=0 , for example when $x \to -\infty$ it decays , doesn't it? So why we do not apply such a condition? I am not sure I got the language about what you said for normalizable. Shouldn't our solution satisfy $\psi*\psi=1$?

Comment: Normalizable means $\psi$ satisfies $\int\psi *\psi =1$.  Neither term $A$ nor $B$ decays as $x\rightarrow \infty$.  They both oscillate with constant amplitude.  Any wave function has to remain finite, so it is not necessary to specify that as a condition.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your question properly but I think may be you're asking in one dimensional potential well problem why we don't consider the case where x tends to infinity.

If that's the question then , you need to see the fact that out side the well boundary, i.e., x>l the potential is infinite and thus the particle inside the box isn't capable of escaping from the box. So the wave function is confined within the range 0<x<l.

If that's not what you're looking for then I'm sorry.

Comment: I added some explanations to my question , maybe it's clearer now